# rails' form_for, form_tag no longer working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have multiple forms in my rails app that were working perfectly up until last night. With no actual modification of anything to do with forms, none of my form tags are even showing up in the HTML anymore.

Is there any quick fix for this, or any known reason this would occur? Thanks!

Comment: What modifications did you make that have nothing to do with your forms? Are you getting error messages?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

There were no errors, but what happened was I had two helper methods I created last night, one or both of them were conflicting with names used in form generation.

My methods were `concat` and `tag_length`, which both seem likely to have interfered :p